# how to add a custom background image in GUI in Matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

Currently I am working on a mat-lab GUIDE and would like to include an image as the background of the GUI. I know to add images which exist in image processing toolbox,but if i need to add image of my own then what is the procedure or code or is there a way i can add images to the image processing toolbox. Here is how i imported the already existing image,

```
I=imread('eight.tif');
hi = imagesc(I)
colormap gray
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put image file name in `imread` if the image is in the same folder with your GUIDE, or put the full path to the image if the image is in different folder, i.e:

```
function myAxes_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
axes(hObject);
I = imread('myfig.jpg');
% or
I = imread('C:\Windows\myfig.png');
imagesc(I);
% fill up to the whole figure and turn off ticks
set(hObject, 'XTick', [], 'YTick', [], 'Units', 'normalized', 'Position', [0 0 1 1]);
```